# How can I store the value of a promise and use it once resolved?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum

I am currently developing an app which interacts with uniswap, and I have developed a Wrapper class to contain the info and variables I'll need about some pair (e.g DAI/WETH).

As some of this values are asynchronous, I have coded a build() async function to get those before calling the constructor, so I can store them. I want to store the result of this build function, which is an instance of the class I have defined, inside a variable to use it later, but I need to know whether the Promise that that build function returns is resolved before using it, so how can I make it?

Here is the code of the class:

```
'use strict'
const { ChainId, Fetcher, WETH, Route, Trade, TokenAmoun, TradeType, TokenAmount } = require('@uniswap/sdk')
const { toChecksumAddress } = require('ethereum-checksum-address')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3()
const chainId = ChainId.MAINNET;
let tok1;
let tok2;
let pair;
let route;
let trade;

class UniswapTokenPriceFetcher
{
    constructor(async_params)
    {
        async_params.forEach((element) => {
            if (element === 'undefined')
            {
                throw new Error('All parameters must be defined')
            }
        });

        this.trade = async_params[0];
        this.route = async_params[1];
        this.pair = async_params[2];
        this.tok1 = async_params[3];
        this.tok2 = async_params[4];
    }

    static async build(token1, token2)
    {
        
        var tok1 = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, toChecksumAddress(token1))
        var tok2 = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, toChecksumAddress(token2))
        var pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(tok1, tok2)
        var route = new Route([pair], tok2)
        var trade =  new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(tok2, web3.utils.toWei('1', 'Ether')), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT)
        return new UniswapTokenPriceFetcher([trade, route, pair, tok1, tok2])

    }

    getExecutionPrice6d = () =>
    {
        return this.trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6);     
    }

    getNextMidPrice6d = () =>
    {
        return this.trade.nextMidPrice.toSignificant(6);     
    }
}




module.exports = UniswapTokenPriceFetcher
```

Thank you everybody!

EDIT: I know Uniswap only pairs with WETH so one of my token variables is unneccesary, but the problem remains the same! Also keep in mind that I want to store an instance of this class for latter use inside another file.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting when you call the build static method? Or update you answer with any attempts you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either call the build function with `await`

```js
const priceFetcher = await UniswapTokenPriceFetcher.build(token1, token2)
```

or followed by `then`

```js
UniswapTokenPriceFetcher.build(token1, token2).then(priceFetcher => {...})
```

I don't see any other way.

Comment: On the first solution, how do I know when priceFetcher is ready to be used?

Comment: The line after `const priceFetcher = await UniswapTokenPriceFetcher.build(token1, token2)` will not run until priceFetcher is available. Therefore on the next line you can be sure that `priceFecter` will contain the value resolved by the promise. That's how `await` works.

Comment: So a call to the function without the await keyword would execute next lines of code while waiting for build to complete?

Comment: Yest. A call to an async function without await returns a promise and moves on to the next line while the promise is still pending. If you instead put await in front of the async function, Javascript will keep doing something else until the promise resolves a value. Only then javascript will assign the resolved value to `priceFetcher` and move to the next line.